# Bind data from 2 datasets into one tablix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have to combine data from 2 different datasets to single Tablix which should be sorted on Date Time.

For Example:
Dataset1:

```
DateTime                      Product       Employee  
2020-08-13 18:10:53.263       ABC             A
```

Dataset2:

```
DateTime                      Product       Employee  
2020-08-13 19:10:20.000       XYZ             A
```

ResultSet:

```
DateTime                      Product       Employee  
2020-08-13 18:10:53.263       ABC             A  
2020-08-13 19:10:20.000       XYZ             A
```

Note: I cannot combine data from both the datasets at the database level as the datasets refer to 2 different datasources.

I have an idea on LOOKUP but I guess that can be used at column level but my case I need to display the data at row level from 2 datasets based on Datetime sort.

Could someone please suggest if there is a way to achieve this.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What are the datasources? e.g. SQL Server and Oracle or SQL and csv file etc? There 'may' be a way round it if I know where your data comes from?

Comment: @AlanSchofield : Both the datasources are from SQL server databases(2 different databases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the databases are on the same server then you can simply UNION the results together something like

```
SELECT [DateTime], [Product], [Employee]
    FROM [database_A].[mySchema].[myFirstTable]
UNION ALL
SELECT [DateTime], [Product], [Employee]
    FROM [database_B].[myotherSchema].[myOtherFirstTable]
```

If they are on different servers then Create a linked server (details on how to do this are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15))

Then use the same query but preceding the 2nd reference with the server name / link server name

```
SELECT [DateTime], [Product], [Employee]
    FROM [database_A].[mySchema].[myFirstTable]
UNION ALL
SELECT [DateTime], [Product], [Employee]
    FROM [myLinkedServerName].[database_B].[myotherSchema].[myOtherFirstTable]
```

Now you'll have a single dataset with all your data and no headache!

---

If you have two existing Stored Procs

---

If you have two SP then you can still do this but in a slightly different way. Something like

```
CREATE TABLE #t([DateTime] DateTime, Product varchar(50), Employee int)

INSERT INTO #t
    EXEC #myFirstProc

INSERT INTO #t
    EXEC #mySecondProc

SELECT * FROM #t
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah, we can do it at database level. But my case, I need at report level because it requires good amount of time for me to implement that dynamically from code and I dont have sufficient time. Please suggest me if we have any option to do this in the report.

Comment: As fars I know I know there is no way to do this directly in SSRS. If you search for things like "SSRS UNION 2 datasets" you will see lots of examples of how to mimic the results but none of them give you a single tablix with all the results in as you are expecting.

Comment: I update the answer in case you are currently using stored procs and that is what is holding you back.